# Sandbox-friendly installation of NSRecentDocumentsMenu without Nib

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am working on a project that does not (currently) use any nib files at all.

I'm trying to figure out whether there is any way to add the NSRecentDocumentsMenu Open Recent menu that doesn't require use of a private API.

The below link is all I've managed to find thus far:
http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2007/07/10/working-without-a-nib-part-5-open-recent-menu/

Can anyone offer insights?

Comment: Is this is a document-based app?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to figure out whether there is any way to add the NSRecentDocumentsMenu Open Recent menu that doesn't require use of a private API.

The following link is for a document-based app in swift without using nibs:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cfvsz11oe00lnp5/DocBased_swift.zip?dl=0

It uses a modification of menu code found in this reference:

https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E145-setting-up-a-document-based-app

The demo may be run in Xcode by creating a macOS app using swift and a XIB interface, although we will not use the XIB.  Create a new file called main.swift and remove the existing AppDelegate class.  Copy/paste the source code found above into the main.swift file (use import Cocoa instead of Foundation).  When you hit the Run button you will notice that the menus are grayed out and there is no Open Recent menu item.  To fix this be certain to add Cocoa NSDocument Class and Role to the info.plist (see image in folder above).  The Cocoa NSDocument Class should be the nameOfYourApp.Document for swift or just plain Document for objc.  When the Run button is hit after making these additions you should have a document based app with a functioning Open Recent menu item.  Please post followup if there are problems.

Objc source code is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dvs1u6lpk4l5xhq/DocBased_objc.zip?dl=0

Instructions are similar to those for swift, except a macOS app is created using objective-c.  Copy/paste the source code into main.m after deleting what Xcode supplied.  For simplicity, also remove AppDelegate and the Document class (if you checked 'Document based' in the setup), although you could use them if you so desire. The info.plist will also have to be amended with the two additions as noted above.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Document : NSDocument {
 NSWindow *window;
 NSTextView *txtView;
}

- (void) buildWindow;
@end

@implementation Document

 - (id) init {
 if (self = [super init]) {
   [self buildWindow];
 }
 return self;
 }

 + (BOOL)autosavesInPlace {
  return YES;
  }

- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
  return [[txtView string] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  }

  - (BOOL) readFromURL:(NSURL *) absoluteURL ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
  NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:absoluteURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:outError];
  [txtView setString:str];
  return YES;
  }

- (void) buildWindow {

 #define _wndW  780
 #define _wndH  700

window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH )
 styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable
 backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered defer: NO];
[window center];
[window setTitle: @"Test window"];
[window cascadeTopLeftFromPoint:NSMakePoint(600,0)];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];

// **** Window Controller is Necessary **** //
NSWindowController *windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc]initWithWindow:window];
[self addWindowController: windowController];

// ****** NSTextView with Scroll ****** //
NSScrollView *scrlView = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 20, 50, _wndW - 40, _wndH - 70 )];
[[window contentView] addSubview:scrlView];
[scrlView setAutoresizingMask: NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable ];
[scrlView setHasVerticalScroller: YES];
txtView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW - 40, _wndH - 70 )];
[txtView setUsesFindBar:YES];
[txtView setEditable:YES];
[txtView setAllowsUndo: YES];
txtView.automaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled = NO;
[scrlView setDocumentView: txtView];

// ***** Quit btn ***** //
NSButton *quitBtn = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 5, 40, 40 )];
[quitBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleCircular ];
[quitBtn setTitle: @"Q" ];
[quitBtn setAutoresizingMask: NSViewMinXMargin];
[quitBtn setAction:@selector(terminate:)];
[[window contentView] addSubview: quitBtn];
}

@end


@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

- (void) buildMenu;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

  - (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender {
  return NO;
  }

  - (void) buildMenu {
  NSMenu *mainMenu = [NSMenu new];
  [NSApp setMainMenu:mainMenu];

 // **** App Menu **** //
  NSMenuItem *appMenuItem = [NSMenuItem new];
  [mainMenu addItem:appMenuItem];
  NSMenu *appMenu = [NSMenu new] ;
  [appMenuItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
  NSString *appName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName];
  NSString *aboutTitle = [@"About " stringByAppendingString:appName];
  [appMenu addItemWithTitle: aboutTitle action:@selector(orderFrontStandardAboutPanel:) keyEquivalent:@""];
  [appMenu addItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem]];
  [appMenu addItemWithTitle: @"Quit" action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"];

  // ******** File Menu ********//
  NSMenuItem *fileMenuItem = [NSMenuItem new];
  [mainMenu addItem:fileMenuItem];
  NSMenu *fileMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"File"];
  [fileMenuItem setSubmenu:fileMenu];
  [fileMenu addItemWithTitle: @"New" action: @selector(newDocument:) keyEquivalent:@"n"];
  [fileMenu addItemWithTitle: @"Open..." action: @selector(openDocument:) keyEquivalent:@"o"];
  [fileMenu addItem: [NSMenuItem separatorItem]];
  [fileMenu addItemWithTitle: @"Close" action: @selector(performClose:) keyEquivalent:@"w"];
  [fileMenu addItemWithTitle: @"Save" action: @selector(saveDocument:) keyEquivalent:@"s"];
  [fileMenu addItemWithTitle: @"SaveAs..." action: @selector(saveDocumentAs:) keyEquivalent:@""];

  // ******** Edit Menu ********//
  NSMenuItem *editMenuItem = [NSMenuItem new];
  [mainMenu addItem:editMenuItem];
  NSMenu *editMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit"] ;
  [editMenuItem setSubmenu:editMenu];
  [editMenu addItemWithTitle: @"Undo" action:@selector(undo:) keyEquivalent:@"z"];
  [editMenu addItemWithTitle: @"Redo" action:@selector(redo:) keyEquivalent:@"Z"];
  [editMenu addItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem]];
  [editMenu addItemWithTitle: @"Cut" action:@selector(cut:) keyEquivalent:@"x"];
  [editMenu addItemWithTitle: @"Copy" action:@selector(copy:) keyEquivalent:@"c"];
  [editMenu addItemWithTitle: @"Paste" action:@selector(paste:) keyEquivalent:@"v"];
  [editMenu addItemWithTitle: @"Delete" action:@selector(delete:) keyEquivalent:@""];
  [editMenu addItemWithTitle: @"Select All" action:@selector(selectAll:) keyEquivalent:@"a"];
  [editMenu addItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem]];
  NSMenuItem *findItem = [editMenu addItemWithTitle:@"Find" action:@selector(performTextFinderAction:) keyEquivalent:@"f"];
  [findItem setTag: NSTextFinderActionShowFindInterface];

  }

- (void) applicationWillFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
[self buildMenu];
}

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
}
@end

int main() {
NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
[application setDelegate:appDelegate];
[application run];
return 0;
}
```

Unable to post image of plist. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and downvote removal.  I used the links because of the length of the source code and inclusion of an image, but if SO doesn't mind a lengthy code post that's fine with me.  I also understand that over time the links could become broken.  It would be even better if I could post the plist image, but hopefully a description is sufficient.  Over the years SO has been a valuable resource for me and I am happy to give back a little and contribute in areas that I have knowledge of.